# Why jenkins job is SUCCESS when there is AssertionError and ReferenceError with mochawesome test framework?

Tags: jenkins, mocha.js

Here is a fragment of Jenkins console output:

46 passing (1s)
  2 failing

1) 判断errorCode是否为0:
     ReferenceError: result is not defined
      at Context. (deviceQuery.js:45:22)

2) #登录接口测试
       判断errorCode是否为0:

```
  AssertionError: expected '1' to equal '0'
  + expected - actual

  -1
  +0

  at Context.<anonymous> (Login.js:86:16)
```

But the job was SUCCESS, why? Can i let the build FAIL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We got a same problem with maven, we must add a Option to the Jenkins Job
In our case we had to add `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false` to the `MAVEN_OPTS`
I am not sure if this can help you but you can try to find out if such an option like these exist for mochawesome.

Comment: Not find the same option, but thanks for your advise!